# index out of range in self in torch

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch

I ran the following code in google colab notebook:

```
import torch
from transformers import AutoModelForCausalLM, AutoTokenizer

def load_LLM(default="EleutherAI/gpt-neo-1.3B", device='cpu'):
    # Load the tokenizer for the specified model
    tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(default)

    # Load the model for the specified model
    model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(default).to(device)

    return model, tokenizer

import torch
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
device = "cpu"
# prompts = ["one plus two equals to", "twenty-two plus two equals to"]
batch_size = 8  # Adjust the batch size depending on the memory available on your device
max_length = 512  # Set the maximum length for truncation

# 1. Tokenize the prompts
tokenizer.add_special_tokens({'pad_token': '[PAD]'})

# Create a DataLoader to handle batching
def collate_fn(batch):
    return tokenizer(batch, padding=True, truncation=True, max_length=max_length, return_tensors="pt").to(device)

dataloader = DataLoader(prompts, batch_size=batch_size, collate_fn=collate_fn)

# 2. Generate text using the model
output_strings = []
for input_tokens in dataloader:
    with torch.no_grad():  # Turn off gradient tracking to save memory
        generated_tokens = model.generate(input_ids=input_tokens["input_ids"].to(device),
                                   attention_mask=(input_tokens["input_ids"] != tokenizer.pad_token_id).to(device),
                                   temperature=0.0)

    # 3. Use the tokenizer to decode the output
    batch_output_strings = [tokenizer.decode(token, skip_special_tokens=True) for token in generated_tokens]
    output_strings.extend(batch_output_strings)

print(output_strings)
```

However when I tried to run this I'm getting the following error:

```
Setting `pad_token_id` to `eos_token_id`:50256 for open-end generation.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-5170b8b3983e> in <cell line: 20>()
     20 for input_tokens in dataloader:
     21     with torch.no_grad():  # Turn off gradient tracking to save memory
---> 22         generated_tokens = model.generate(input_ids=input_tokens["input_ids"].to(device),
     23                                    attention_mask=(input_tokens["input_ids"] != tokenizer.pad_token_id).to(device),
     24                                    temperature=0.0)

9 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/torch/nn/functional.py in embedding(input, weight, padding_idx, max_norm, norm_type, scale_grad_by_freq, sparse)
   2208         # remove once script supports set_grad_enabled
   2209         _no_grad_embedding_renorm_(weight, input, max_norm, norm_type)
-> 2210     return torch.embedding(weight, input, padding_idx, scale_grad_by_freq, sparse)
   2211 
   2212 

IndexError: index out of range in self
```

I noticed that the code works fine with smaller strings like "1+1=" or "23+2". Can anyone tell me what might be the issue. You are free to run the code on any colab notebook and check it.